# _svgdotjs_svg_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Filter is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, vaadin, svg.js

Im trying to use Svg.filter.js in a project using webpack (Vaadin) and typescript, but I stumpled upon a weird import issue.

I need to use the constructor Filter out of svg.filter.js , but this constructor is in the module svg.js.

Now, my import looks like this:

```
 import  "@svgdotjs/svg.filter.js";
 import {SVG,Filter} from "@svgdotjs/svg.js";
```

When running this, i get the following error:

```
_svgdotjs_svg_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Filter is not a constructor
```

So my question is:

How do I handle this error in webpack. Since im using methods recommended by examples i think its an webpack issue.

Comment: What makes you think that the constructor is in the svg.js module (spoiler it's not)? Just import it from the filter module and ofc import svg.js first please

Comment: TS2305: Module '"../../../../node_modules/@svgdotjs/svg.filter.js/svg.filter.js"' has no exported member 'Filter'.

Comment: If you check svg.filter.js it uses the same module as svg.js...

Comment: I guess webpack is grabbing the wrong version then. `@svgdotjs/svg.filter.js/src/svg.filter.js` has an export as well as the corresponding d.ts file

Comment: any idea how to correct that? @fuzzyma

Comment: You could import the file with the path shown in my last comment.

Comment: I am having the same problem, anyone has the answer?